# Change Referer Header of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, header, referer

I am using FireFox browser and it change Referer Header from its Ads-Ons (Plugin) REFCONTROL.
Is there any other way to change IE Reference Header from window registry or anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do this from within IE without writing a native code browser extension.

You can trivially do this using the Filters tab in Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com)